# MySQL query returns 0 rows in PHP, actual records in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to get rows from table - specific range of rows to be clear. My query looks like this (just part of the code):

```
SET @i=0;
SELECT * FROM images WHERE (@i:=@i+1) BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

What is does is get row number of rows and returns rows, whose row number is in given range. When I run this query in phpmyadmin, I can see the result of the query (the actual rows in that range), however the number of rows from query is 0. I am pretty sure the problem is with this part

```
WHERE (@i:=@i+1)
```

I have searched throught other answers, but the reason was always in php, not the query itself.

Comment: Then why tag it with php if the issue is in mysql/phpmyadmin ?

Comment: You should show us how the query is invoked from your php code. Did you check if the above query returned any errors within php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use phpMyAdmin, each query opens a new database connection, and user variables don't persist between connections. Set the variable in a subquery that you join:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM images AS i
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) AS x
WHERE (@i := @i + 1) BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a million!

Comment: @barmar well, the i variable persists, because we get 10 results in phpMyAdmin; it's just the row counting that does not work. I tried initializing i to 5 and got only 5 rows in the results.

Comment: Did you send both queries in one command? Maybe it's just showing the row count for the first query. `SET` doesn't return anything, so its row count is 0.